# Using Perl to conditionally add tag to XML file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am not a developer in any way, but a network security guy. I need to insert a tag and value for an element if it does not already exist.

Here's a snippet of my XML file

```
<NessusClientData_V2> 
    <Policy> 
    ... 
    <Report> 
    ... 
        <ReportHost name="1.2.3.4"> 
        ... 
            <HostProperties> 
            ... 
                <tag name="HOST_END">Thu Sep 17 17:23:19 2015</tag> 
                <tag name="system-type">general-purpose</tag> 
                <tag name="operating-system">MS WIN</tag> 
                <tag name="ssh-auth-meth">password</tag> 
                <tag name="ssh-login-used">backup</tag> 
                <tag name="local-checks-proto">ssh</tag> 
                <tag name="host-ip">1.2.3.4</tag> 
                <tag name="HOST_START">Thu Sep 17 17:00:14 2015</tag>
            </HostProperties> 
            ...
```

I need to check each `ReportHost` element and create a

```
<tag name="mac-address">
```

if it doesn't already have one.

My output needs to contain all of the original information, but only needs to be added to.

Comment: Your question will probably be closed as off-topic because you appear to be asking for some code to be written for you for free. That's kinda rude and isn't what Stack Overflow is about. You should read [**What topics can I ask about here?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which says *"Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it"* which doesn't seem to apply to you. In any case I don't see where the *value* for tha MAC address comes from

Comment: Ok, that's fine. I have to upload files to a gov't system that requires a stupid mac-address entry, even if it's bogus.

Comment: have just been trying to find any ideas on how to do this in an automated fashion. I'm not a programmer, so this probably wasn't the best forum.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, not a forum. Think of it as the Wikipedia of solutions to programming problems. By asking a question you're opening a new topic that you think belongs here but hasn't been created before

Comment: Is this a cross site dupe of http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1146167 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) to do this. The following code iterates all `HostProperties` nodes and checks them for the existance of a `tag` with *name* `mac-address`, and if it's not there, inserts one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

# at most one div will be loaded in memory
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        '//ReportHost/HostProperties' => sub {
            my $seen = 0;
            foreach my $elem ( $_->children('tag') ) {
                if ( $elem->atts->{name} eq 'mac-address' ) {
                    $seen++;
                    last;
                }
            }
            $_->insert_new_elt( 
              'last_child', 
              'tag' => { name => 'mac-address' }, 
              'barfoo' 
            ) unless $seen;
        }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parse( \*DATA );
$twig->flush;

__DATA__
<NessusClientData_V2>
    <Policy>
    <Report>
        <ReportHost name="1.2.3.4">
            <HostProperties>
                <tag name="HOST_END">Thu Sep 17 17:23:19 2015</tag>
                <tag name="system-type">general-purpose</tag>
                <tag name="operating-system">MS WIN</tag>
                <tag name="ssh-auth-meth">password</tag>
                <tag name="ssh-login-used">backup</tag>
                <tag name="local-checks-proto">ssh</tag>
                <tag name="host-ip">1.2.3.4</tag>
                <tag name="HOST_START">Thu Sep 17 17:00:14 2015</tag>
            </HostProperties>
        </ReportHost>
        <ReportHost name="127.0.0.1">
            <HostProperties>
                <tag name="HOST_END">Thu Sep 17 17:23:19 2015</tag>
                <tag name="system-type">general-purpose</tag>
                <tag name="operating-system">MS WIN</tag>
                <tag name="ssh-auth-meth">password</tag>
                <tag name="ssh-login-used">backup</tag>
                <tag name="local-checks-proto">ssh</tag>
                <tag name="host-ip">127.0.0.1</tag>
                <tag name="HOST_START">Thu Sep 17 17:00:14 2015</tag>
                <tag name="mac-address">foobar</tag>
            </HostProperties>
        </ReportHost>
    </Report>
</Policy>
</NessusClientData_V2>
```

You will have to replace the `->parse(\*DATA)` with a `->parse_file` and maybe add some random mac address.

Comment: Looks like it @Sobrique. I've not been checking perlmonks in a while. It makes my eyes hurt unfortunately. :-/

Comment: I do from time to time. It seems even more prone on 'bad formatting syndrome' than SO though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered on [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1146167), and with a bit more of an XML sample, I'll recycle the answer. For this trick, I'd use `xpath` to query your XML, rather than walking the tree. The reasoning behind this is because `xpath` lets you query element, attribute and attribute content in a single statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parsefile( 'your_file.xml' );

#search for "HostProperties" nodes within the tree. You can
#be more specific about this if you need to. 
foreach my $HP ( $twig->get_xpath('//HostProperties') ) {
    #check if it has a "tag" element with a "mac-address" "name" attribute.
    if ( not $HP->get_xpath('./tag[@name="mac-address"]') ) {
        #insert a new element at the end of the entry. 
        $HP->insert_new_elt( 'last_child', 
                     'tag', { 'name' => 'mac-address' },
                     "DE:AD:BE:EF:F0:FF" );
    }
}

#note - pretty printing helps reading, but might
#cause some problems with certain XML constructs. Shouldn't in your specific example though. 
$twig->set_pretty_print("indented_a");
$twig->print;

#to save it to a file:
open ( my $output, '>', 'processed.xml' ) or die $!;
print {$output} $twig -> sprint;
close ( $output );
```